# How to rearrange rows of dataframe according to number array

Tags: r, dataframe

`x` is a dataframe.

```
> x
     TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08
TGTT                            1
TGTG                            2
TGCG                            2
TGGA                            1
TCCG                            1
TCAG                            2
```

How can I rearrange `x` according to a number array. Such as
`match <- c(1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4)`
the result of `x` should be

```
> x
     TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08
TGTT                            1
TGCG                            2
TGTG                            2
TCAG                            2
TCCG                            1
TGGA                            1
```

I used `x <- x[match,]`, it didn't work.

Comment: `cbind()` followed by `arrange()` maybe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with the "drop" issue. When R reads a matrix with only a single column, that 2nd dimension (columns) gets "dropped." This can be fixed by adding a simple "drop = FALSE" argument after the dimensions.

```
Object[Row,Column, drop = FALSE]
```

So for your dataset perhaps you are looking for:

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1,1,2))
dimnames(x) <- list(c("TGTT", "TGTG", "TGCG", "TGGA", "TCCG", "TCAG"), "TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08")
match <- c(1,3,2,6,5,4)
x[match,,drop = F]
     TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08
TGTT                            1
TGCG                            2
TGTG                            2
TCAG                            2
TCCG                            1
TGGA                            1
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
columnname <- colnames(x)
x <- as.data.frame(x[match,])

colnames(x) <- column_name
```

I can use some other information to get `rownames` by `match` order and rename `x`.

Do you guys have any easy and good ideas?